# Interactive Choropleth Map Using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, country, world-map

I found a code for creating the worldmap that uses the shapefile from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/
Download Countries v4.1.0

```
shapefile = 'data/countries_110m/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp'
datafile = 'data/obesity.csv'

gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]
gdf.columns = ['country', 'country_code', 'geometry']
gdf.head()


    country                     country_code      geometry
0   Fiji                                 FJI      (POLYGON ((180 -16.06713266364245, 180 -16.555...
1   United Republic of Tanzania          TZA      POLYGON ((33.90371119710453 -0.950000000000000...
2   Western Sahara                       SAH      POLYGON ((-8.665589565454809 27.65642588959236...
3   Canada                               CAN      (POLYGON ((-122.84 49.00000000000011, -122.974...
4   United States of America             USA      (POLYGON ((-122.84 49.00000000000011, -120 49....
```

Many people use this file, and everything is ok.
But when I open the file, it only has one column `'geometry'`

```
KeyError: "['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3'] not in index"
```

And I can't understand if something is wrong with the file, or is it something wrong with the code?

Update. I think the problem is with this error. Sometimes this works, sometimes this error appears

```
DriverError: Unable to open ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shx or ne_110m_admin_0_countries.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you renamed the columns:

`gdf.columns = ['country', 'country_code', 'geometry']`

where `admin` is now `country` and `ADM0_A3` is now `country_code`

Comment: The shapefile itself only show one column `'geometry'`, when I run the code `gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)` , but supposed to have other columns. And I can't understand why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. To solve this error `DriverError: Unable to open ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shx or ne_110m_admin_0_countries.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.`
I just created a folder with 7 same files of different format: **.cpg, .dbf, .prj, .README, .shp, .shx, .VERSION**
and used the .shp file from that directory, and the Jupyter was able to read that file correctly with all of the columns.